# Phonegap 3.3 / 3.4 - event firing issue android

Tags: android, events, cordova, listeners

When I close (read: send to background) the app, the "pause" isn't called and when I reload the app the "resume" isn't called.

Any tips on getting this to work would be greatly appreciated!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    onLoad();
    });      
</script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    };

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
        document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
        appStartUp();
    };

    // Handle the resume event
    //
    function onResume() {
        setTimeout(function() {
        alert("onResume");
        }, 0);
    };
    // Handle the pause event
    //
    function onPause() {
        setTimeout(function() {
        alert("onPause");
        }, 0);
    };
</script>
```

Ok, in addition to this, the app seems to be reloading each time from the start, so the resume and pause don't do anything, as the app is loading again.

I've added android:launchMode="singleTask" to the android manifest (via config.xml). But it still loads again.

Comment: After speaking to a phonegap rep, I moved the addeventlisteners to the index.html

Comment: Could you please post the code that worked for you?

Comment: Turns out, my problem was resolved by loading `<script src="phonegap.js"></script>`. See http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready for a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick for me for Jellybean:

It still isn't working for KitKat...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
alert("device ready");
appStartUp();
};

// Handle the resume event
//
function onResume() {
setTimeout(function() {
alert("onResume");
}, 0);
};
// Handle the pause event
//
function onPause() {
setTimeout(function() {
alert("onPause");
}, 0);
};   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't get `pause` event if you close your app.

The `pause` event will be triggered when your app is put into the background.

If you now open the app you will receive the `resume` event.

Usually pressing the *back* button will exit your app. You can put your app into background if you use the *home* button.

Comment: My mistake - I meant send to background, not close. If I press the back button it will exit the app as you say, and the home button puts it into the background... But the events just do not fire... Is there an error in my code?